# Java Swing Applet---JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, textfield, jformattedtextfield

I'm writing my first Java Swing Applet, and wanted to include a JFormattedTextField that only allowed integers greater than 0. 
The bit of my code is this;

```
try {
      SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              JFormattedTextField txt = new JFormattedTextField(Object 1);
              add(txt); //creating the JFormattedTextField
          }
      });
  } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println("Please enter new number."); //Catching any numbers less than one. 
  }
```

Comment: Your first place of call should be [How to use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html).

Comment: I don't think this is how formatted text field works. I'd suggest using a `DocumentFilter`, but I can't remember if it employees it own.  Instead, I'd recommend using a `JSpinner` instead

Comment: Yes, JSpinner is definitely the way to go.  It not only provides built-in support for minimum and maximum values, it actually uses a JFormattedTextField for its input.  Essentially, JSpinner is a "ranged JFormattedTextField."